# How to model UserDetail with phone number registration only in spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to build spring boot app where user can register with it **mobile phone only**. No login with username and password.

I'm using spring boot as my backend and also include spring security to secure my rest endpoints.

When user verify its phone number with OTP I want to generate jwt in order to secure my rest endpoints.
The thing is I don't know how to model spring security userDetails and userDetailService since I don't care about username and password only phone number for registration

Any help will be appreciated
Thank you in advance

Comment: The username is the phonenumber.

Comment: and password? I don't need password since the username send a code it receives via sms

Comment: Then dont use it. Just leave it empty.

Comment: I see..haven't thought about it :-). thanx

Answer (score 0):

Use this implementation for overriding the username with phone number:

```
@Table(name = "tbl_user", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "phone_number")
})
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", unique = true)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```